# Is it possible to run tesseract.js (from https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js) under GraalVM using graal.js to do OCR in Java?

Tags: java, graalvm, tesseract.js

I am trying to do OCR on an image file from Java. So I decided to use Tesseract.js from https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js and invoke it via graal.js functionality in GraalVM but could not get it to work.

Here is what I tried.

```
public static final String TESSERACT = "src/tesseract.js";

private static void tesseract(String imageFile) throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("=== Calling Tesseract === ");
    try(Context context = Context.create())
    {
        context.eval(Source.newBuilder("js", new File(TESSERACT)).build());
        Value Tesseract = context.getBindings("js").getMember("Tesseract");
        Value recognize = Tesseract.getMember("recognize");
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String result = recognize.execute(imageFile).asString();
        long took = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        System.out.println("Tesseract call took: " + took + "ms with result: " + result);
    } // context.close() is automatic
}
```

And it compiles but at runtime throws this exception:

```
=== Calling Tesseract === 
Exception in thread "main" ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at <js> spawnWorker(src\tesseract.js:286:8848-8853)
    at <js> _delay(src\tesseract.js:504:16140-16184)
    at <js> recognize(src\tesseract.js:472-481:15321-15620)
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Value.execute(Value.java:457)
    at com.mycompany.app.JsApp.tesseract(JsApp.java:98)
    at com.mycompany.app.JsApp.main(JsApp.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
```

```
Anyone know to to fix this?
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that `tesseract.js` expects to be run in the browser. The window is not defined because instead of running tesseract.js in the browser, you run it in a different JavaScript runtime.

To solve your issue, I would just run the Tesseract OCR using Tess4j. Tess4j is a JNA wrapper around Tesseract (just like `tesseract.js` is a browser wrapper).

Comment: I see that tesseract.js runs inside Node.js which is not a browser. In fact if you look at the bottom of the page at https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js you'll that there are several ways to use it.

Tess4j was having some other issues with JNI - that's exactly why I tried this approach.

Comment: The fact that it references the window object (which is only available in browsers) makes me think that it only runs in the browser. They don't have any examples of running within another environment. But I haven't worked with tesseract.js before so I might be wrong.

Comment: Agreed. They may have a version that does not reference that object. Asking in github.